# I've read that std::list is terrible. Could someone compare it to .Net's List<> type? I'm coming to C++ from C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, generics, c++11

I read recently that std::list is horrible compared to "intrusive" lists for a host of reasons having to do with constant time lookups and reallocating with operator new...which I think that I'm following. Could one of you guys compare it to the .Net generic list? Is Bjarne's statement that vector should be used unless you have a really good reason kind of like using .Net generic list for any homogenous group of stuff?

Comment: .NET's `List<>` is the equivalent of C++'s `std::vector<>` -- it's not a linked list at all, but a dynamic array-based container.

Comment: Each container has its place - in other words, it all depends on context - i.e. how it's used

Comment: Every container has a place, but for the majority of questions `std::vector` is the answer.

Comment: Wow...was that newb enough to warrant downvoting? Tough crowd...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`std::list` is actually more like .NET's `LinkedList<T>`.  `std::vector` is very similar to `List<T>`.

Both containers have their place, but the "array like" semantics you get with `std::vector` and `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` are the ones that are most commonly required and provide the expected performance in more cases.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I was getting tripped up on some of the terminology.